# Eclipse debugger error Model proxy installed notification job

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Whenever I open the breakpoint column under the debugger, it gives the error as

```
Model proxy installed notification job
Child Count Update
```

Details gives

```
An internal error occurred during: "Model Proxy installed notification job".
java.lang.NullPointerException
An internal error occurred during: "child count update".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using Xdebug on Eclipse Juno on my Mac OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: Try to update Eclispe (and plugins). Does the error still appear?

Comment: Check for updates mentions there is nothing to update

Comment: I just found this in Eclipse bugreports: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=223992

Comment: This report indicated the bug has been fixed which is not the case

Comment: I would really like to help but that's too deep for a non eclispe developer. (and not reproducable for me) I would consider to file a bug at bugs.eclipse.org .

Comment: This has been filled for more than 2 yrs now, with no update https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340179

Answer (score 5):

I know its too late to answer but hope this will work for anybody.

I also got same issue for my android eclipse (ADT bundle).

I just removed break point tab from debug perspective and added it back to same.

from `Windows -> Show View -> Breakpoints.` and it worked for me. now i am able to toggle a break point and it do not through any error.

Comment: I just got this error message while debugging Perl code using eclipse with EPIC. Google recommended this. When I saw your response, I realized, I had just deleted a few lines of code, containing a breakpoint. Removing that breakpoint fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know I fixed it by updating, also updated the issue in the eclipse bug tracker.

The bug is not fixed in lastest Eclipse PHP PDT 3.0.X version available in its main web: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

This is how I fixed it:
Go to Breakpoint tab, press ok three times until the error goes out. Right click inside the Breakpoint Tab, delete all Breakpoints. After that delete the Breakpoint tab so its not seen again in tabs. Close Eclipse.
Now use AtfCleaner and CCleaner, delete all temporary files and any possible registry entry with conflicts.

Now update to versión 3.1.1 (probably you dont need to do the above things but it worked for me so Im not sure at all):
To update to version 3.1.1 you must update it with the Eclipse updater, pointing to:
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release
Update only one by one element to ensure everything is right downloaded and installed.

More info:
http://eclipse.org/pdt/release-notes/3.1.1/

Same happens with Subversion, if you want to fix it you must manually search for the lastest update repository, update to the lastest version and fix the bad connectors.
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x
http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA
Download only the lastest svn version or Eclipse will not connect to a svn repository.

Eclipse is full of bugs and having to know where to download or update or fix something is a real pain. Cant understand how its possible that there is not still a standard way of updating Eclipse and its components and information is not updated and clear in its main web. Its incredible the product is shipping with outdated and conflicting components.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response. But as I mentioned in question I am using Eclipse Juno on Eclipse platform 4.2 and not the Eclipse PDT.

Comment: Sorry so much, didnt saw that. There must be something in the code change from Eclipse PDT 3.0 to Eclipse PDT 3.1 which fixed it.

I can suggest to read the faq of known issues, maybe there is some setting which could help: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.2.html#KnownIssues
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/Eclipse_SDK_4.0_FAQ
I would also suggest trying to manually update eclipse if you havent done that already:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

Maybe you can update something in 4.2 or in 4.3 which fixes it.

Comment: The last thing I can suggest is to download Eclipse again and check if the original uncompressed version is stable. If you can debug and see the breakpoint tab without problems, leave Eclipse and compare both folders (the problematic one and the downloaded original one) to see what files are different.